# Slow soft body physics causes the animation player to stop

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

I just started using Blender.

I'm trying to roll a ball running down a long pipe. Just letting the soft body physics run drops down the fps in solid view mode under 1 fps , which causes the animation player to stop.

My guess is that the objects("pipeline") its collapsing with is just to big?! But shouldn't this somehow be an easy job to do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to bake the softbody calculations (cache section in the softbody settings). Without a bake blender is trying to calculate everything on the fly in real time, hence the drop to 1fps.

Answer (score 1):

In your case (base along pipeline) the rigid body system is better suited to do the simulation, since it isn't imperative for the ball to deform.

Nevertheless creating a simpler collision geometry is helpful.

1. Remove the current softbody and collision settings.
2. Duplicate the *track* object. This *track_duplicate* will be used to create a collision object with less resolution. Remove the wireframe modifier of the *track_duplicate* and decimate it with a decimate modifier. (I first used the *planar* option, applied it the used it with the *collapse* option and applied it again.)
3. Make the *track_duplicate* a passive rigid body object and set its shape to **mesh**.
4. Make the *ball* an active rigid body.
5. Hide the *track_duplicate* object (it will still be used for collisions) and show the original highres mesh.

[image: ball along decimated track]

You only need softbody object if they're supposed to deform.

Comment: i know i should thank you... anyway thank you! Awesome explanation:)

Comment: @horn If an answer helped you, you can upvote it. The additional information from your (deleted) answer can be edited in the question, which will bump the thread automatically. If you want a higher playbackrate you could consider caching the simulation or [baking it to keyframes](https://youtu.be/Ay7TcUwJnJc).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the current soft body physics solver in Blender is not fast enough to consider it as a usable thing, especially when making animations where the objects in the scene could be pretty complex with lots of polygons.

However, try lowering the number of polygons of your objects and see how much things speed up. Also, in *Soft Body Edges* settings turn off *Edge* and *Face* collision. You may also reduce the number of solver iterations in *Soft Body Solver*